Use flask_jwt_extended with multipart/form-data from React.js frontend
I'm using React.js as the front-end and Flask as the back-end for an app. I'm modifying code found in this blog post here.
I am able to get everything to work when I submit a request from the front-end where the content-type is application/json. Where it breaks is when I try and submit a file upload that needs to passed to the back-end using content-type multipart/form-data and jwt_required(). The route on the Flask back-end works without the jwt_required() decorator and other routes that don't have multipart/form-data seem to work as well. So I think it has to do with the content-type.
Here's the code:
React.js - App.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

function App() {

  // user info for handling log in
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function getUserInfo(response) {
    const code = JSON.stringify({ code: response.code });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
    };
    try {
      // Pass the response to the backend
      const flaskResponse = await axios.post('/api/google-login', code, config);
      console.log("Flask Authentication Response:");
      console.log(flaskResponse);
      return flaskResponse.data; // Return the response data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error; // Rethrow the error to be caught by the caller
    }
  };

  // handle the user login with google
  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    flow: "auth-code",
    onSuccess: async (codeResponse) => {
      var loginDetails = await getUserInfo(codeResponse);
      setLoggedIn(true);
      setUser(loginDetails.user);
    },
    onError: (error) => alert('Login Failed:', error)
  });

  // handle the upload button
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const url = '/api/read-file';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', userFile);
    formData.append('fileName', userFile.name);
    formData.append('jwt_cookie', Cookies.get('access_token_cookie'));
    const token = Cookies.get('access_token_cookie');
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'accept': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    console.log(url);
    axios.post(url, formData, config)
      .then((response) => {
        // handle the response from flask
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
      });
  };

return (
    <div className="app">
      <main className='content'>
        {!loggedIn && <>
          <button onClick={() => login()}>Sign in with Google</button>
        </>
        }
        {loggedIn && <>
          <div className="file-upload">
            <form>
                <h3>Drag and drop a file here, or click to select files</h3>
                <input type="file" accept=".csv,.xlsx,.xls" onChange={(e) => { handleFileUpload(e) }} />
                <div className='submit'>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={!file}>Upload</button>
                </div>
             </form>
          </div>
       }
      </main>
    </div>
   );
}


Flask - server.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token, JWTManager, jwt_required, get_jwt_identity

import requests

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


app = Flask(__name__)

# Access the environment variable
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = # google client id
GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY = # google secret key

# Initialize JWTManager - handles authentication
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = # my super secret key
app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['cookies']
jwt = JWTManager(app)

@app.route('/api/google-login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    # the request from the front end - info we need is in 'code'
    auth_code = request.get_json()['code']
    
    data = {
        'code': auth_code,
        'client_id': GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,  # client ID from the credential at google developer console
        'client_secret': GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY,  # client secret from the credential at google developer console
        'redirect_uri': 'postmessage',
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
    }
    
    response = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data=data).json()
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {response["access_token"]}'
    }
    user_info = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', headers=headers).json()
    
    jwt_token = create_access_token(identity=user_info['email'])  # create jwt token
    response = jsonify(user=user_info)
    response.set_cookie('access_token_cookie', value=jwt_token, secure=True)

    return response, 200

@app.route('/api/read-file', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required()
def read_file(header=0):    
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    df = parse_file(request, header)
    return(df.to_json(orient='records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


This ended up being a POST method issue and not multipart/form-data. I had to pass a CSRF token from the front end to the back end to allow POST methods. I'm not posting my answer here because it feels very hacky and I'm still working on a way to improve it. I currently am passing the CSRF token in the header as opposed to a cookie. This is probably not the best way to do it and might even pose a security risk
